# Logistic Regression test input format help in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I do have the below dataset.

[image]

I've created **Logistic Regression** out of it and checked Accuracy and is working fine. So now requirement is I've a new data with **Age 30** and **EstimatedSalary 50000** and I would like to predict whether Purchased will be 0 or 1. How to pass the new values **30** and **50000** in my python code.

Below is the python code which I've used.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
%matplotlib inline

dataset = pd.read_csv(r"suv_data.csv")

X=dataset.iloc[:,[0,1]].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,2].values

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

sc=StandardScaler()
X_train=sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=sc.transform(X_test)

classifier=LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test)

accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)*100
```

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: You need to add more details. Y presume these are the columns `dataset.iloc[:,[2,3]].values` in your data. But `I've a new data with Age 30 and EstimatedSalary 50000` what do you mean with new data? A txt? A dataframe?

Comment: The sample data you provided is not consistent with the code snippet: this line `X=dataset.iloc[:,[2,3]].values` will throw an error since you only have 3 columns so the column indexes are only `[0,1,2]` and column 3 is not there.

Comment: I just edited it, forgot to make changes while posting the question.

Comment: the new values 30 and 50000 are already in the dataset or not ?

Comment: @seralouk they are not in the dataset. I would like to pass them in the python code.

Comment: that's easy. see my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, to evaluate (i.e. call `.predict` in `sklearn`) a trained model, you need to input samples that have the same shape as the samples the model was trained on.

In your case I suppose (see my comment on your question) you wanted to have samples with `Age` and `EstimatedSalary` in the training set using `Purchased` as label.

Then, to test on a single sample just try this:

```
single_test_sample = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[30], 'EstimatedSalary':[50000]}).iloc[:,[0,1]].values
single_test_sample = sc.transform(single_test_sample)
single_test_prediction = classifier.predict(single_test_sample)
```

Note that you can also add more values in the test dataframe `Age` and `EstimatedSalary` columns, now I only added the sample you were interested in. If you add more, the model will output a prediction for each row in the test dataframe.

Also note that your code and mine, will also work without this `.values` at the end of the train/test set as sklearn already provides functionality with pandas dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for that, the code works fine. I've tried adding more values by editing your code and is working.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear but I understand that you need to use the fitted model to predict a new sample.

**After having fitted your model just use this:**

```
new_sample = np.array([[30,50000]]) # 2D numpy array

new_sample_sc = sc.transform(new_sample)

y_pred_new = classifier.predict(new_sample_sc)
print(y_pred_new)
```

Comment: The OP was using pandas, this solution will work but is more cryptic and error prone. In addition does not show that `sklearn` can actually go hand in hand with pandas and there is no need to transform data into `numpy` arrays.